# Jenkins 2.x disable initial admin setup

Tags: security, automation, vagrant, jenkins

we're using Jenkins as a cron server adding/starting crons via api. We created a vagrant box installing the jenkins. Since version 2.0 jenkins require to create an admin account ([link](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30749)) before [disable the security](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security) in config.xml.
If no admin is created in jenkins, the config.xml (with disabled security) is overwritten.
Is there any way to avoid this (maybe create an admin via bash command)?

Answer (score 5):

[Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jenkinsci-users/Pb4QZVc2-f0/KbQllak3NgAJ) state following

```
java -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false -jar jenkins.war
```

the

> **`-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false`**

disables the setup wizard & the admin user stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Providing the mentioned property in Jenkins parameters isn't enough. Just tested it. In order to really disable the setup wizard and "unlock" Jenkins you should also use a Groovy init script with contents like:

```
#!groovy

import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.util.*;
import jenkins.install.*;

def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()

instance.setInstallState(InstallState.INITIAL_SETUP_COMPLETED)
```

More details available following [this link](http://www.riptutorial.com/jenkins/example/24925/disable-setup-wizard)

Comment: It works for admin account password set but Jenkins is still asking for installing plugins